# how to test the DOM events using jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

**Here it is my component function**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.addPlantListener();
  }
```

**which is calling inside the method**

```
addPlantListener = () => {
    if (this.plantListener === undefined) {
      const ddl = document.getElementById('ddlSourcePlant');
      Iif (ddl !== undefined && ddl !== null) {
        this.plantListener = ddl;
        ddl.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.closePlantDropdown);
      }
    }
  }
```

**here addEventListener is calling again from mouseleave event**

```
closePlantDropdown = (dropdown) => {
    dropdown.fromElement.click();
  }
```

**i'm using to test this JEST and this functions are in react js** 
how do i test this functions, i'm unable to test the addEvent Listener and mouse leave events any body can suggest please a way to accomplish this thank you. :)

**my component is just a dropdown list**

**current my test method is like this**

```
it('test method', () => {
        const component = mount(h(SetSource, { ...props }));
        component.instance().componentDidUpdate();
        const ddl = component.find('#ddlSourcePlant');
** what goes here to test next lines and methods **
      });
```

Comment: What are the problem with your tests currently? Normally jest comes with jsdom so it shouldn't be a problem. Maybe you just need to initiate the document.body for your tests but otherwise it should work

Comment: @Axnyff how do i test this flow in a single test and what are the expectations to assert here